# Is it possible to costumize a listview like this?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I'm doing a Hotel PMS (Property Management System) and i'm wondering if it is possible to costumize an listview item like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJ9M.png). I only know how to add simple text items and I'm not really sure if it can do something like that.

Ps: Soo sry that my question is not a coding problem, but I can't find answers to my question anywhere :(

Comment: In Windows Forms no chance. In WPF probably, but I guess there are already some 3rd party controls out there, that will do the job (also for Winforms).

Comment: ok, I'll try to find some 3rd party controls, thx :)